# I am Working with Xcode 4.5 and i traced a warning to this "format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) "

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I am faced the below **error** :
`format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]`

and my **code** is :

```
appDelegate.reportString = [NSString stringWithFormat:queryString];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line? What's wrong with just `appDelegate.reportString = queryString` in this case?

Comment: I am just copy combination of strings from 'queryString' to 'appDelegate.reportString'    but i was run the project in xcode 4.5 i faced the above error.Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't seem to want to format the string (ie no parameters to use with the format string) but just copy it, the better call to use is [[NSString stringWithString:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithString:)

```
appDelegate.reportString = [NSString stringWithString:queryString];
```

If `queryString` is an immutable string and not an `NSMutableString`, you don't need to copy it but can just use;

```
appDelegate.reportString = queryString;
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "`stringWithFormat`" prefers a compile time string literal, for example:

```
appDelegate.reportString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"this is a series of numbers %@", @"123456"];
```

whereas in your case, all the compiler sees is a variable ("`queryString`") and nothing else.

If queryString doesn't change, why not do:

```
appDelegate.reportString = queryString;
```

which increments the retain count of queryString.  Or you can do "`[[NSString alloc] initWithString: queryString]`" or "`[queryString copy]`" to create a brand new retained copy.

And of course Joachim's answer is also good too.  +1 to him!